# Wordpress images not showing when migrated to localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, jetpack, w3-total-cache

I recently started learning Wordpress about a few weeks ago. All-in-One WP Migration plugin helped me migrate a website from the web to my localhost. Upon uploading it to my local server, I noticed that no images are showing on the front end, other functions seems to be working just fine. I found out a while later that the reason as to why the it wasn't showing is because the path towards the images seems to be broken, thus producing a 404 error (image not found).

Images are pointing towards "localhost/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg" rather than "localhost/**MyWebsite**/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg" which I suspect is the reason as to why no images are showing.

Here are the plugins I mainly use:

- Woocommerce (and other plugins related to this)
- Jetpack
- W3 Total Cache
- All In One WP Security
- Smush
- WP Mail SMTP

Tried to deactivate all plugins and reverted the website to its default theme (twenty seventeen) but the issue still remains.

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Hi Bryant, maybe check your WordPress Address (URL) and 
Site Address (URL) on -> /wp-admin/options-general.php, see if the name of the folder where your project is is added to the url. http://localhost/MyWebsite

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `site-url`/wp-admin/options-permalink.php, select "Post name" and save the changes.

Comment: Permalink has been set to "Post Name" but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a band-aid solution but this worked well for me as I only intend to use my local server for staging purposes (to see if I can update a certain plugin without crashing the website). I copied the wp-content folder and pasted it one directory higher.

This topic is still open for discussion to people who are experiencing this type of problem and wants a real solution to solve this (not the one I gave)